# Transition when CSS change with State - React

Tags: css, reactjs, state, css-transitions

I have a sidebar that minimize when i click on a button. I use a Class component and I have a state to deal with it.

If `true`, the sidebar width is 200px.
if `false`, it is 70px.

```
render() {
    const SidebarStyled = styled.div`
      width: ${this.state.sidebarOpen ? '200px' : '70px'};
      position: fixed;
      left: 0px;
      top: 0px;
      height: 100vh;
      background-color: #0c1635;
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
      justify-content: space-between;
      align-items: center;
```

I would like to set a transition and I have no idea how.
The only solutions I found was with functional components, and my client want only class Components.

Any help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess, You are creating a `const SidebarStyled` and based on the `state.sidebarOpen` deciding the value of `width`, but the thing is the style is resolved and applied to the component and it does not change with the state change.
I would suggest you create two style const one with `width: 200px` and other with `70px` and based on the `state.sidebarOpen` apply appropriate style const.